# Importing BetaAnalyticsDataClient from @google-analytics/data returns Webpack 5 errors

Tags: node.js, angular, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to create a custom dashboard on the angular app I am building. I want to use the data from Google Analytics 4 using Google Analytics Data API. I've successfully ran the scripts provided in their tutorial Using Node.JS client libraries (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries?hl=en_US).

I've ran the quickstart script they have provided using Node.JS and was able to get the expected response. However, when I try to ran the same script on my angular app via importing the script to fetch returned values, "ng serve" returns webpack 5 errors.

The issue was importing the BetaAnalyticsDataClient. Whenever I import it, the nodemon returns webpack errors.

The structure is like this:
[simple component structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w8xh.png)

1. I have a 'site-statistics.component' with its html and scss files.
2. I have a script named 'google-analytics.ts' inside the subfolder "services".
3. site-statistics.component imports an exported function from google-analytics.ts

If the issue is my usage of the Google Analytics Data API client library, I want to know how I would be able get the response from the script and send it to my angular component.

Options I've tried, but failed:

1. Tried adding a resolve.fallback on webpack.config.ts. However, issue still persists.
2. Tried setting paths to each packages on my TSCONFIG.JSON.
3. Tried using react-scripts-rewired

If the issue is the way I use the Google Analytics Data API client library, I want to know how I would be able get the response from the script and send it to my angular component.